# Async property in c#

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

In my windows 8 application there is a *global* class where there are a few static properties like:

```
public class EnvironmentEx
{
     public static User CurrentUser { get; set; }
     //and some other static properties

     //notice this one
     public static StorageFolder AppRootFolder
     {
         get
         {
              return KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary                    
               .CreateFolderAsync("theApp", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists)
               .GetResults();
         }
     }
}
```

You can see I want to use the application root folder somewhere else in the project, so I make it a static property. Inside the getter, I need to make sure the root folder exists,otherwise create it. But the `CreateFolderAsync` is an async method, here I need a synchronized operation. I tried `GetResults()` but it throws an `InvalidOperationException`. What is the correct implementation? (The package.appmanifest is correctly configured, the folder is actually created.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Good solution:**
Don't make a property. Make an async method.

*"I hate await, how can I make everything synchronous?"* solution: [How to call asynchronous method from synchronous method in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343594/how-to-call-asynchronous-method-from-synchronous-method-in-c)

Comment: I'd prefer get the result of the task synchronously. Just want to know how.

Comment: Don't fight against asynchronous operations. It will only give you headache.

Answer (score 17):

I suggest you use [asynchronous lazy initialization](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/08/asynchronous-lazy-initialization.html).

```
public static readonly AsyncLazy<StorageFolder> AppRootFolder =
    new AsyncLazy<StorageFolder>(() =>
    {
      return KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary                    
          .CreateFolderAsync("theApp", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists)
          .AsTask();
    });
```

You can then `await` it directly:

```
var rootFolder = await EnvironmentEx.AppRootFolder;
```

Answer (score 4):

use the await keyword

```
 public async static StorageFolder GetAppRootFolder() 
 { 
          return await ApplicationData
                      .LocalFolder
                      .CreateFolderAsync("folderName");
 }
```

and in your code

```
var myRootFolder = await StaticClass.GetAppRootFolder(); // this is a synchronous call as we are calling await immediately and will return the StorageFolder.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea.

```
public Task<int> Prop {
    get
    {
        Func<Task<int>> f = async () => 
        { 
            await Task.Delay(1000); return 0; 
        };
        return f();
    }
}

private async void Test() 
{
    await this.Prop;
}
```

but it creates a new Func object for every call
this would do the same

```
public Task<int> Prop {
    get
    {
        return Task.Delay(1000).ContinueWith((task)=>0);
    }
}
```

You can't await a set since `await a.Prop = 1;` is not allowed