# Using "await" in a converter (IValueConverter) not working?

Tags: c#, async-await, converters, imagesource

I have a converter in my Windows Phone application but it seems you cannot use "await" methods in it?

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
{
    _IDataService = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IDataService>();

    string imageUrlId = (string)value;

    byte[] imageByte = await iDataService.GetImage(imageUrlId);

    return LoadImageAsync(imageByte);
}
```

If I make the method async Task it says IValueConverter has no method Task async. This converter returns type ImageSource.

Answer (score 4):

You can't change the signature of the `Convert` method since you have to provide an implementation for all the methods of the `IValueConverter` interface.

What I usually do is loading in the images of the view-model asynchronously from the backend, not on the UI thread. With the proper bindings, the images will be displayed on your UI as soon as it is loaded.

Comment: I see, and can I use await async in one of my model classes? In the get from a property?

Comment: No, you can't use the async keyword on a property. (See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12384309/async-property-in-c-sharp-4-5) Just make your GetImage method of your IDataService interface asynchronous. Loads the image from your view-model by calling the async GetImage and assign the BitmapImage to one of the property of the view-model. :)

Comment: Yes I got it! But I need to go to the detail page and then back to see the images, when I login I see my ListView with empty images, going to a detail page and back they are shown.

Comment: I'm glad you got it :)

Answer (score 1):

I have an older answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15003827/async-implementation-of-ivalueconverter/15007717#15007717) that mostly addresses this problem (but see below - one of the helper types is somewhat dated).

The core of the problem is that asynchronous work is actually improper for a *value converter* to do. What you're really doing is telling WPF "to cast this type to this other type, first call a web service..."

So, IMO any asynchronous behavior is better done in other parts of the system (ViewModel, service layer, etc). Asynchronous work can be easily represented in a ViewModel by using my [`NotifyTask` type](https://github.com/StephenCleary/Mvvm.Async/blob/master/src/Nito.Mvvm.Async/NotifyTask.cs).

However, my older answer does have a working "asynchronous value converter". Note that the `TaskCompletionNotifier` type in that answer has [a newer implementation](https://github.com/StephenCleary/Mvvm.Async/blob/master/src/Nito.Mvvm.Async/NotifyTask.cs).

Comment: Now I need to know how to update the xaml UI after a background task is done.

Comment: @Bayern: That's what the `NotifyTask` type is for. I have an [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn605875.aspx) with example usage.

Comment: Ahaha that looks interesting! That will work for this problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34244838/images-downloaded-in-a-async-method-shown-after-coming-back-from-a-detail-page

Comment: @Bayern: From what I can tell of the question, it looks like yes. `NotifyTask` is specifically for updating MVVM UIs with the results of background operations.

Comment: OK then I will try this. I also found out that when I scroll down and back up the images are also shown.

Answer (score -2):

You could use .result () after async function call

Like,  byte[] imageByte = iDataService.GetImage(imageUrlId).result ();

Comment: You could, but generally you never should.