# Images downloaded in a async method shown after coming back from a detail page, so actually updating the UI after a background task

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, async-await, backgroundworker

I have a ListView with some stuff in and that List has some images that I load in a background task. But when I login and see the LIstview the images are not shown if I go to a detail page from one of my ListViewItems and come back the images are shown.

This is my "async" task:

```
 private async void DownloadImage(ImageObject imageObject)
    {
        ImageByte = await _IDataService.GetImage(imageObject.Id);

        ImageObjectImageSource = await LoadImageAsync(ImageByte);

        imageObject.ImageObjectSource = ImageObjectImageSource;
    }
```

Comment: Looks like not the loading is the problem, instead may be you need to refresh your screen to show the ready loaded images.

Comment: @DieterMeemken if I refresh the page the ListView is loading again and the same happens

Comment: Try to avoid that. They should only be loaded, if they are empty. And that should not be done in refresh, only when initialising (may be except, when they can change).

Comment: @DieterMeemken yes I know but how can i update my UI after the images are loaded? Like when I got to a detail page and then back then the images are visible

Comment: I would suggest some kind of event, that is called after an image is loaded and the receiver is doing the refresh. So the images will pop in one by the other.