# UWP WIndows-10 Loading images in app

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2015, windows-10-universal

I have a C# app targeting Windows UWP platform. App displays images in list view. Based on the query made, these images can come from either app's

1. container(**/Assets/** folder)
2. Online source
3. Local source

When the image's source is either in app's container or online source I can bind the Image Source to a valid URI in XAML to fetch the image.

When the image's source is local, the url for the image is proprietary & we use our own ***imge_fetch*** api to get the image from our servers.

My problem is how to specify a XAML binding which is capable of taking either a uri(when image is from app's container or online source) or BitmapImage(returned by our **image_fetch** apis)

I have checked this post regarding [IValueConverter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34240426/using-await-in-a-converter-ivalueconverter-not-working)

I want to know, if there are any better/easier way in UWP to do what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may create a view model item class with a source property of type `object`, so that you can assign a `string`, `Uri` or `ImageSource`:

```
public class ImageItem
{
    public object ImageSource { get; set; }
}
```

In XAML, you can directly bind to this property and benefit from built-in automatic type conversion:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Assigning image items my look like this:

```
DataContext = new ImageItem[]
{
    new ImageItem { ImageSource = "ms-appx:///Assets/StoreLogo.png" },
    new ImageItem { ImageSource = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Square150x150Logo.scale-200.png") },
    new ImageItem { ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Square44x44Logo.scale-200.png")) },
};
```