# Sorting WPF datagrid is hanging the whole GUI with IsAsync binding

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, .net-core

I have this IsUpdated property in my WPF application:

```cs
public bool IsUpdated
{
    get
    {
        if (_isUpdated.HasValue)
        {
            return _isUpdated.Value;
        }

        var available = GetAvailableVersion().Result;
        var installed = GetInstalledVersion().Result;

        _isUpdated = IsInstalled && new Version(available).CompareTo(new Version(installed)) <= 0;

        return _isUpdated.Value;
    }
}
```

The GetAvailableVersion() and GetInstalledVersion() methods are async.

And this is how I binded it in XAML:

```cs
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Updated" Width="96" CanUserSort="True" SortMemberPath="IsUpdated">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Name="MyImage" Source="Assets/States/Loading.ico" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsUpdated, IsAsync=True}" Value="False">
                    <Setter TargetName="MyImage" Property="Source" Value="Assets/States/False.ico" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsUpdated, IsAsync=True}" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="MyImage" Property="Source" Value="Assets/States/True.ico" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

I can't sort by column while the IsUpdated property is still loading, it hangs and sometimes crashes.

Do you know how I could solve this nasty issue?

Comment: `.Result` in `GetAvailableVersion().Result` is synchronous

Comment: I know but is there a way to solve this without blocking?

Comment: You may check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6602244/how-to-call-an-async-method-from-a-getter-or-setter and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46584838/wpf-best-practice-for-async-property

Comment: A property is not supposed to invoke long-running operations. Call the methods from somewhere where it makes more sense to call them and then set the `IsUpdated` property once you actually have the results.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the way you do it, but this works fine for me.
Maybe you need to fire property changed after assigning the value to the field.
The field is null until the async action is done. The UI should be notified when the value is finally retrieved.

```
if (!_field.HasValue)
{

    Task.Run(() => <DoAsyncStuff>)
    .ContinueWith(task =>
    {
        if (task.IsFaulted)
        {
            <Error>
        }
        else
        {
            _field = task.Result
        }

    }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());  

}

return _field;
```

`FromCurrentSynchronizationContext` is important, you need `ContinueWith` on the UI thread again, otherwise you will get no propertychanged.

Comment: I have this exception: System.InvalidOperationException: 'The current SynchronizationContext may not be used as a TaskScheduler.'

Comment: I tried this: ```Task.Run(async () => (new Version(await GetAvailableVersion()).CompareTo(new Version(await GetInstalledVersion())) <= 0)).ContinueWith(t => { _isUpdated = t.Result; }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());```

Comment: I think you can write your code in Task.Run synchronously. Without async and await, but .Result (or better .GetAwaiter().GetResult() afair)