# Support for async method calls in property setters

Tags: windows-community-toolkit

This question is related to the MVVM Toolkit provided in the Windows Community Toolkit.

I was wondering if there are any plans to support scenarios where an async method can be called and awaited in a property setter, similar to what's mentioned here from Stephen Cleary's Mvvm.Async library?
[How to call an async method from a property setter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48212998/how-to-call-an-async-method-from-a-property-setter/48217792)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to [this comment](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/issues/3230#issuecomment-616203990), they have a `NotifyTaskCompletion<TResult>`, but it is being replaced by `ObservableObject.SetAndNotifyOnCompletion` in conjunction with `TaskExtensions.ResultOrDefault`.

I recommend asking further questions [directly to the WCT team](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/issues); Stack Overflow is more about programming questions and not questions regarding the future of a specific library.